# TextInputLayout and 2 Imageviews in an horizontal layout

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am trying to align a TextInputLayout and 2 imageViews in a Linear layout with horizontal orientation. For some reason, I am having difficulties positioning them in a horizontal layout. This is what I have tried so far.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.0">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/longDescriptionTextInputLayout"
            style="@style/textfieldbox"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/longDescriptionTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textInputEditTextColor"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_attach_file_black_24dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/Gallery"
            android:hint="@string/longDesc"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix,UnusedAttribute" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_up_black_48dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Attaching an image of the output. The white space in the front is the TextInputEditText.

[image: Final Result]

Comment: what happens if you change Textinput width?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira - The EditText takes up the entire width.

Comment: heven if you set for exemple 25dp of width?

Comment: @If I set the width it accepts, but it looks too small and the hint cuts out

Comment: You can use relative layout to achieve a horizontal layout as well by assigning various parents and aligning them to each other accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your layout.

The first is that your `TextInputEditText` includes these two attributes:

```
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
```

This is the generally-accepted pattern for using `layout_weight`, but weight only makes sense on direct children of the `LinearLayout`, and since this view is wrapped in a `TextInputLayout` they are not appropriate here. Change those to:

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

The second problem is that you are specifying `android:weightSum="3.0"` on your `LinearLayout`, but its direct children only have weights that add up to `2.0`. Either change the value of that attribute to `2.0` or delete the `weightSum` attr altogether (it really only causes problems).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben!. It looks pretty great now!! Best answer +1